# jquery link to input to link trick in my form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a script, but it's not working as expected, and I need help. You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BSGS6/).

I need to implement the following behavior for the URL field only:

1. When you click on the link, the target page opens. This works.
2. When you click on the link's parent `div`, the link becomes an editable `input`. This also happens, but my input field's `id` is taken from an array, e.g. (`url0`, `url1`, `url2`), so when I have more than one URL in the form, only the first one works.
3. When you click outside after editing the input, it becomes a link again.
4. Also, when you double click on the link, it becomes editable.

Thanks in advance for all the answers, and I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: dont asign same id to all the divs

Comment: can't do that, it's an array, and i'm using it in other matters

Comment: then assign a common class name to all the divs and then use class selector to pick divs instead of id

Comment: see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ajaybeniwal203/pZKZY/

Comment: i can't change classes too, they are generated from arrays. need to include some how that array

Comment: Then you're producing invalid HTML which will result in unpredictable behaviour for which you'll have create increasingly complex solutions and error-handling. Stop treating the symptoms, and **treat the problem** (the arrays, apparently, but more likely your page-generating back-end).

Comment: @DavidThomas please see here the last update of this issue maybe you can help please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140689/text-to-link-and-back-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can't* use the same `id` fоr different page elements - this is invalid markup, and, as you can clearly see, leads to invalid behavior. First things first, you might want to fix that in your markup.

If you can't change that (but, once again, *you really should!*), you can use some more involved selectors, for example:

```
$('.cartRight > div > div > a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings("input").findval($(this).text()).show();
    $(this).hide();
})
```

Pretty silly, huh? You can probably use this mess as your last resort, though.

As for double clicking, I wouldn't recommend implementing such behavior; it is uncommon in a Web context, and might be confusing to users. Also, from a technical standpoint, a single click already starts to load the new page; you could use `window.stop()` to stop that if the link is double clicked, but you'll need to manually implement a double click event, since:

> The dblclick event is rarely used. Even when you use it, you should be
>   sure never to register both an onclick and an ondblclick event handler
>   on the same HTML element. Finding out what the user has actually done
>   is nearly impossible if you register both.
>   (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html#dblclick)

I think you should just have a small "edit" button to the right (maybe a "pencil" icon?), instead of going with your current UI scheme. It seems quite confusing to me - not to mention the users...

Comment: please see the last update here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140689/text-to-link-and-back-in-jquery , and please help me with that. thanks a lot